# Create Zendesk Ticket Comment using different AuthorID through APIv2

Tags: zendesk, zendesk-api

Using Zendesk API v2, and .NET library by Elizabeth (https://github.com/mozts2005/ZendeskApi_v2), I'm trying to create Ticket Comments with a different authorID, like so:

```
api.Tickets.UpdateTicket(new Ticket
{
    Id = ticketID,
    Comment = new Comment
    {
        AuthorId = zendeskUserID,
        Body = comment
    },
});
```

Ticket gets updated, but when I load the Ticket, the author ID of the comment is the ID of the API user, and not the author-ID I set as *zendeskUserID*.

Can someone please explain how I can accomplish submitting ticket comment as a different author/user? I have even tried the following to see if anything comes out differently, but nothing has worked:

```
api.Tickets.UpdateTicket(new Ticket
{
    SubmitterId = zendeskUserID,
    ExternalId = zendeskUserID,
    Id = ticketID,
    Comment = new Comment
    {
        AuthorId = zendeskUserID,
        Body = comment
    },
});
```

Please note that the *zendeskUserID* already exists as an External User in Zendesk.

Thanks.

Comment: AuthorId was added to this library only recently. What version did you use?
 Update is: https://github.com/mozts2005/ZendeskApi_v2/commit/4a6afa4034bf9ee3d05fc009686c315c32470855

Comment: Thanks Vincent, but I just updated the NuGet and tried again (with the 2nd code block from above), but it didn't work. The response from "UpdateTicket" has correct ExternalID, but when I load the ticket comments using `api.Tickets.GetTicketComments`, the authorID in the comment is the API User ID. Please note that prior to all this, we do create a user with an ExternalID. Please let me know what else I could be missing. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with your code, so stackoverflow is probably not the best place to solve this. It's probably something around user permissions. What comes to mind that you could check, is eg who is the user who authorised the API, who is the user you are using as author_id (ie roles, groups, who is the assignee/requester of the ticket, etc).